# defining parsing range for a CSV

Tags: python

I`m importing a CSV containing data from year 2002 to 2011 , using this :

```
pair = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1]), delimiter=' ')

names = [] ; date = [] ; open = [] ; close = [] ; min = [] ; max = []

#Parse the CSV file into a list
for data in pair:
    names.append(data[0])
names.pop(0)
```

How would I just keep the 2010 values ? ( from the date column ... )

Comment: What format is the 'date' field going to be in?

Comment: like this : 18/03/2010, so I assume : %d/%m/%Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You test on the date, and keep it only if it's the right year. How this is done depends on what format the date is in, etc. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

for data in pair:
    date = datetime.strptime(data[1], <yourdateformat>)
    if date.year == 2010:
        names.append(data[0])
```

Comment: Oups, sorry. The quotes was left over from where I tested with just data[1][:4], but then I decided that it was unlikely that he used a sane date format. :)

Comment: Hmm, used "date = datetime.strptime(date[1], "%d/%m/%Y" )" but I keep on getting "list index out of range .. " (date is in this format : 18/03/2010

Comment: @Julz: It should be data[1], sloppy typing by me. You might want to use the csv module so that it returns dictionaries instead of lists, btw. It's typically easier to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming date is in '%d/%m/%Y' format

```
names = [data[0] for data in pair if data[1].endswith('2010')]
```